# Make - autogenerated file issue

Tags: makefile

Here is the context :

I am working on a makefile to create a *.h* at every build, including another makefile that will use this header. I can't edit the second one.

Using a target **all** depending on my file, it compiles the first time, creating the missing MyHeader.h. The problem is, when I recompile, the header is not regenerated...

My makefile looks like this :

```
all: myHeader.h

myHeader.h:
    scriptToBuildMyHeader.sh

include obscureAndPrivateMakefile.make
```

I also tried with a .phony target at the beginning. Same result : once created, it won't be regenerated at every build.

PS : I can't call a script before make.

Do some makfile-Masters have any ideas how to deal with that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `myHeader.h` has no dependencies, it will never be rebuilt once it exists. You can work around this by creating a dependency *from* `myHeader.h` to a phony target, eg:

```
forcebuild:
    # dummy; do nothing and don't create this file
.PHONY: forcebuild
myHeader.h: forcebuild
   scriptToBuildMyHeader.sh
```

This will however slow down your build considerably, as the header (and any source files including it) will need to be rebuilt every time.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that because `myHeader.h` does not depend on anything, it exists and is therefore up to date on the second build.  To make sure it is built each time, it has to depend on a non-existent file:

```
myHeader.h: .FORCE
        scriptToBuildMyHeader.sh

.FORCE:
```

The name '`.FORCE`' (or, sometimes, `FORCE`) is used classically.

If you use GNU Make, you could make the 'non-existent' file into a phony target:

```
.PHONY: .FORCE
```

The advantage of this is that (GNU) `make` does not create the file `.FORCE` even if you run `make -t` - which would break the automatic rebuild of the header because that rule depends on there not being a file `.FORCE` that actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible approach:

```
all: clean foo.txt

clean:
    rm foo.txt

foo.txt:
    echo > foo.txt
```

where I'm using `echo > foo.txt` to simulate creation of your header.